# Create list keys object shell Linux

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script to get a list of all the keys of an object from a file in linux terminal.

The file contains something like this:

```
{
    "general" : {
       "street" : "Av. Roadmin",
       "name" : "Batman",
       "phone" : "125478",
       "pets": {
                   "dog":"Hurry",
                   "cat": "Aria"
               }
       }
}
```

And I want the next output:

```
general.street
general.name
general.phone
general.pets.dog
general.pets.car
```

Somebody can help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at the `jq` utility for processing JSON in shell scripts?

Comment: why do you need to do this in shell script -- not the best tool for this job.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jq`, like this:

```
jq -r 'paths(scalars)|join(".")' file.json
```

From: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/78#issuecomment-348818517

If you want to print the keys along with their values:

```
jq -r 'paths(scalars) as $p|"\($p|join(".")): \(getpath($p))"' file.json 
general.street: Av. Roadmin
general.name: Batman
general.phone: 125478
general.pets.dog: Hurry
general.pets.cat: Aria
```